# How do I get the words out of parenthesis using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get words out of parenthesis using a regular expression.

This is my code :

```js
var patt = /(?!.+\))\w+/g;
var str = '( hello ) ehsan (how are) you' ;
console.log( patt.exec(str) ) ;
console.log( patt.exec(str) ) ;
```

**Actual result**

```
you , null
```

**Expected result**

```
ehsan , you
```

**There is a way through negative lookahead?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices to go with. The first would be matching everything inside parentheses then any remaining words. Afterwards you can filter them easily:

```js
var str = '( hello ) ehsan iran (how are) you';
console.log(
  str.match(/\([^()]*\)|\w+/g).filter(x => x[0] !== '(')
)
```

The second approach is tricking a negative lookahead:

```js
var str = '( hello ) ehsan iran (how are) you';
console.log(
  str.match(/\w+(?![^()]*\))/g)
)
```

The first approach is reliable. The second needs all parentheses to be paired and correctly closed.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex uses a negative lookahead `(?!.+\)` to assert what is on the right is not a closing parenthesis. That has matches from the last occurence of the closing parenthesis on because after that, there are no more `)`. Then you match 1+ word characters which will match `you`.

Instead of using a negative lookahead, you coud to use a capturing group:

`\([^)]+\)\s*(\w+)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2MrHA2/1)

```js
const regex = /\([^)]+\)\s*(\w+)/g;
const str = `( hello ) ehsan (how are) you`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

If the engine support [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) with accepts infinite length quantifiers, you might also use a positive lookbehind:

`(?<=\([^()]+\)) (\w+)`

```js
const regex = /(?<=\([^()]+\))\s*(\w+)/g;
const str = `( hello ) ehsan (how are) you`;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  console.log(m[1]);
}
```

Comment: Tanks for answer, but how use of  negative lookahead ?

Comment: The negative lookahead does an assertion for what follows, but you want to check if the string that you want to match is not within parenthesis so on the left and on the right. You can check if what is on the right is a closing parenthesis but you can not be sure that it is or is not on the left.

Answer (score 1):

**You can do it like this**

First remove all the character between `()` and than split it with `space`.

```js
var str = '( hello ) ehsan (how are) you' ;

let op = str.replace(/\(.*?\)/g, '').trim().split(/\s+/)
console.log(op);
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to solve it is `split`:

```js
const input = '( hello ) ehsan (how are) you';
const output = input.split(/\(.+?\)/);

console.log(output);
console.log(output.filter(v => v));
console.log(output.filter(v => v).map(v => v.trim()));
```

Comment: If you change the regex to `/\s*\(.+?\)\s*/` you won't need to trim the results...

Answer (score 0):

The below statements give the ouptput that you expect.

```
var patt = /(?!.+\))\w+/g;
var str = '( hello ) ehsan (how are) you' ;

var arr = str.split(/\([\w\s]*\)/);   // [ '', ' ehsan ', ' you' ]
var arr = arr.filter((s) => s!== ""); // [ ' ehsan ', ' you' ]

var s = ("" + arr).trim(); 
console.log(s); // ehsan , you
```